# Use method names from one of my classes usign reflection for creating a maven archetype

Tags: maven, velocity, archetypes

I am a complete novice creating maven archetypes, I have been reading a lot of posts before I decided to ask this question. I want to create a template to build new projects following an structure defined by an interface (created by me):

```
package com.jh.interfaces;
public interface VideoPlayerInterface {
    void play();
    void pause();
    void rewind();
    void stop();
    void fastFordward();
}
```

I would like to create a class which overrides whose methods, something like this:

```
package com.jh.impl;
public class VideoPlayerCustom implements VideoPlayerInterface {
    public void play(){}
    public void pause(){}
    public void rewind(){}
    public void stop(){}
    public void fastFordward(){}
}
```

In order to do that, I found topics in SO that used reflection to do similar stuff with Java classes, but I wasn't able to get results using my interface even with a simple operation to start:

```
public class ${library-name}Client
{
    #set( $year = $package.getClass().forName("java.util.Date").newInstance().getYear() + 1900 )
    #set( $name = $package.getClass().forName("com.jh.interfaces.VideoPlayerInterface").getSimpleName() )

    public void ${name}${year}(){}
}
```

${year} contains the current year (it works fine), but ${name} fails when creating project from maven archetype:

```
generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.ArchetypeGenerationFailure: Error merging velocity templates: Invocation of method 'forName' in  class java.lang.Class threw exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jh.interfaces.VideoPlayerInterface at archetype-resources/src/main/java/__library-name__Client.java[line 10, column 39]
```

Has anyone gone through a similar issue? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach :

Use the reflation related stuff in Java code, get the declared methods and add methods array/list to the velocity context.

```
String sourceClassName = "com.jh.interfaces.VideoPlayerInterface";
try {
    Class sourceClass = Class.forName(sourceClassName);
    Method[] methods = (Method[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(methods, sourceClass.getDeclaredMethods());
    context.put("methods", methods);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then you can write your template something like this :

```
package com.jh.impl;
public class VideoPlayerCustom implements VideoPlayerInterface {
    #foreach ($method in $methods)
        public void $method.getName()(){}
    #end
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I am a complete newbie with archetype, where should I attach that Java code? Till now I just could create the a file depending on an attribute value.